# Can legends in PowerBI Pie Chart be hidden if value is zero?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-custom-visuals

[image: All data by Category]
[image: June2020 Data By category]

In a Power BI Pie Chart total 8 legends(category) are there and count is distributed by category as shown in 1st pic. When I select Only June 2020 (2nd pic), there is data only for 5 category and accordingly it is distributed in Pie Chart. In both images, there are 8 legends are shown in right side.
Is it possible to hide the legend if there is no value for that legend. for example : in 2nd image, possible to hide remaining 3 legends and only shown legends for which data is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Agustin I created below measure:

FilterMeasure = INT(NOT(ISEMPTY(Filter(TableName,TableName[Category]=TableName[Category]))))

and below is filter pan:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

First create a measure using the following dax function:

```
Cross Filter = INT( NOT( ISEMPTY( FAC_TABLE ) ) )
```

Select your visualization, open the filter panel and drag the measure in the **Filter on this visual** option. Finally select the option equal to 1. The following image is in spanish but you will get the idea.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Many Thanks Agustin, it helped a lot in what I exactly wanted.. Thanks